# Why does append method modify a variable within a class in python?

Tags: python, class, append

I am trying to understand the class type in python. And just when I thought I understood it, I find this. I don't understand why when I use the append method it is saved for other variables. Example:

```
class flower:
    tpe="standard"
    register=[]
     
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
amapola=flower()
amapola.register.append("Amapola")
amapola.tpe="spring"
print(f"Type: {amapola.tpe}, register= {amapola.register}")

cactus=flower()
cactus.register.append("Cactus")
print(f"Type: {cactus.tpe}, register= {cactus.register}")
```

Output:

```
Type: spring, register= ['Amapola']
Type: standard, register= ['Amapola', 'Cactus']
```

I don't understand why "amapola" is listed in the "cactus" register. I thought that when the variable "cactus" was created, the list would be set to zero. Or on the other hand, if the register was saved when modified by the variable "amapola", why in "cactus" it returns to "standard" instead of "spring" if it was modified before too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every instance shares the *same* list referenced by the *class* attribute `register`. If you want each instance to have its own register, make it an instance attribute by defining `self.register = []` in `__init__`.

```
class flower:
    tpe="standard"
     
    def __init__(self):
        self.register = []
```

When you write `amapola.tpe = "spring"`, you are creating a new instance attribute that *shadows* the class attribute `tpe`. You may as well get rid of the class attribute and define `tpe` in `__init__` as well.

```
class flower:
    tpe="standard"
     
    def __init__(self, tpe="standard"):
        self.register = []
        self.tpe = tpe

amapola=flower("spring")
amapola.register.append("Amapola")
print(f"Type: {amapola.tpe}, register= {amapola.register}")

cactus=flower()
cactus.register.append("Cactus")
print(f"Type: {cactus.tpe}, register= {cactus.register}")
```

On the other hand, if `register` really *is* supposed to be shared, so that `flower.register` contains the names of all the instances you define, then keep `register` as a class attribute.  `amapola.register.append` is not an *assignment* to a name; it's a method that *mutates* an existing value.